# Writing a file sequentially

Tags: multithreading, io, delphi

I've written a procedure which allows serialized writing of a stream. I don't in any way consider this done, but this is the beginning of it. I know there are other implementations out there like this, but they tend to be either too primitive or too heavy. This is an attempt to simplify serializing the output stream.

The reason I cannot use the normal writing classes is due to the fact these data are written by separate threads. And, also, when writing the output, the position of that stream needs to be considered as well.

So, I tried to store the output streams in memory until all previous ones are already written into it.

Do you see anything critically wrong with it?

```
var
  NextPosition: Int64 = 0;

procedure HandleOutput(OutHandle: TObjectDictionary<Integer, TStream>;
  Position: Int64; Outstream, mystream2: TStream);

begin
  TMonitor.Enter(OutHandle);
  try
    if NextPosition = Position then
    begin
      mystream2.CopyFrom(Outstream, 0);
      Inc(NextPosition);
      while OutHandle.TryGetValue(NextPosition, Outstream) do
      begin
        mystream2.CopyFrom(Outstream, 0);
        OutHandle.Remove(NextPosition);
        Inc(NextPosition);
      end;
    end
    else
      OutHandle.Add(Position, Outstream);
  finally
    TMonitor.Exit(OutHandle);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Maybe you should also show the code that creates the threads and populate the `TObjectDictionary`. Point being, are you adding the streams to the dictionary at creation or when corresponding thread is finished? I assume you are creating the threads in the order you want corresponding streams added to the file.

Comment: The big problem with writing data from different threads is that you can't trust that it'll be written down in a certain order. Therefore, my first question is: do you *need* the data to be in a certain order?